# npm install pnotify throwing peer dependency errors

Tags: node.js, pnotify

Running npm install --save pnotify for a Node app that lists Pnotify as a dependency throws these warnings:

```
ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @pnotify/bootstrap4@5.2.0
npm WARN Found: bootstrap@3.4.1
npm WARN node_modules/pnotify/node_modules/bootstrap
npm WARN   peer bootstrap@"^3.4.1" from @pnotify/bootstrap3@5.2.0
npm WARN   node_modules/pnotify/node_modules/@pnotify/bootstrap3
npm WARN     @pnotify/bootstrap3@"5.2.0" from pnotify@5.2.0
npm WARN     node_modules/pnotify
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer bootstrap@"^4.4.1" from @pnotify/bootstrap4@5.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/pnotify/node_modules/@pnotify/bootstrap4
npm WARN   @pnotify/bootstrap4@"5.2.0" from pnotify@5.2.0
npm WARN   node_modules/pnotify
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: bootstrap@4.6.2
npm WARN node_modules/bootstrap
npm WARN   peer bootstrap@"^4.4.1" from @pnotify/bootstrap4@5.2.0
npm WARN   node_modules/pnotify/node_modules/@pnotify/bootstrap4
npm WARN     @pnotify/bootstrap4@"5.2.0" from pnotify@5.2.0
npm WARN     node_modules/pnotify
```

Then running npm start throws this:

```
ERROR in ./src/Helpers/Functions.js 5:0-46
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'pnotify/dist/es/PNotify' in '<node app root>]/src/Helpers'
```

... and the same error with /PNotifyStyleMaterial.js  and PNotifyButtons

I tried installing with npm install pnotify -legacy-peer-deps but get the same error.

I tried manually installing all three missing files from https://unpkg.com/browse/pnotify@4.0.0/ (highest version for which I could find raw files) but install still fails.

I tried npm install webpack --save-dev (which I think uses pnotify) but get the same error.

Did a full reinstall from the app root

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm cache clean --force
npm install
```

... same error

How do I resolve that dependency glitch so I can get my app to run?
(npm version: 8.11)

Answer (score 0):

This should be threated as a hack, not recomended command but may help you fix These deps errors.

```
npm install --force
```

This Will ignore a Lot of things and not Ensure correct installation, but can help you fix for while.

Comment: Tried this. Same error.

Comment: Does you have deleted node_modules foder before tried run command?

Comment: Yep. Did a clean reinstall of the whole thing. Same error.

When I start the server it seems to run, but my app throws 503s. Can't tell if they're related.